# NServiceBus 4 without RavenDB

Tags: ravendb, nservicebus, nservicebus4

Is there anyway to use NServicebus 4 without installing RavenDB?  We are using 2.5 and I would like to upgrade to 4 but this will be a tough sell if we have to install RavenDB on our production server.  Is there any work around?

Comment: http://particular.net/articles/persistence-in-nservicebus

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. You can use NServiceBus without RavenDB.
While, the default subscription storage (for pub/sub), default saga persister and default timeout persister is RavenDB, using custom initialization like shown below, you can switch them to NHibernate persistence instead, in which case you won't need RavenDB.

```
class CustomInit : INeedInitialization
{
    public void Init()
    {
        Configure.Instance.UseNHibernateSubscriptionPersister();
        Configure.Instance.UseNHibernateSagaPersister();
        Configure.Instance.UseNHibernateTimeoutPersister();
    }
}
```

And also the app.config for using NHibernate is further simplified in 4.x

```
         <connectionStrings>
<add name="NServiceBus/Persistence" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=nservicebus;Integrated Security=True"/>
```

and specify the other needed NHibernate settings like below in appSettings:

```
    <appSettings>
<!-- dialect is defaulted to MsSql2008Dialect, if needed change accordingly -->
<add key="NServiceBus/Persistence/NHibernate/dialect" value="NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2008Dialect" />
<!-- other optional settings examples -->
<add key="NServiceBus/Persistence/NHibernate/connection.provider" value="NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider" />
<add key="NServiceBus/Persistence/NHibernate/connection.driver_class" value="NHibernate.Driver.Sql2008ClientDriver" />
```

Comment: An even terser option is NHibernatePersistence.UseAsDefault();

Comment: I'm sure this is the correct answer but I think I may have deeper problems.  I have a publisher modeled after the PubSub.sln in the samples folder that nsb installed.  However, I have changed it to structuremap and to point to the message that I plan to send.  I ammended the EPConfig to use NHP.Useasdefault() and the app.config as recommended above except I pointed it to my local.  Now when I debug it starts to consoles and just hangs.  Doesn't hit any breakpoints.  ug.  any thoughts?

Comment: I have to table this for now so I'll mark you as the correct answer.  Thanks for your help

Comment: I found that if the tables do not exist in the database, they are not created.  Is there a recommended way to create those?  I ended up manually executing installers from NServiceBus.NHibernate DLL from test EXE to create tables.  After that I continuously get primary key violation exceptions, but things work nonetheless.