# nservicebus 4.0.3 how to disable ravendb

Tags: ravendb, nservicebus

With 3.3.x version we were able to configure disable raven dB, but could find anY with 4.0.x version other workaround which I found was to disable timeout manager.

Any better way to sort it out?

Comment: possible duplicate of [NServiceBus 4 without RavenDB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18153756/nservicebus-4-without-ravendb)

Comment: I am not using any persistence at all neither Saga/Timeout, how do i do that?

Comment: Do you want to use SQL Server instead?

Comment: no I don't want any persistance.

Comment: Why exactly don't you want any persistence?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like if you add the following to your endpointconfig it won't try to hit Raven DB. Unless you're using sagas or pub sub. Then I think some sort of storage is required. For my purpose, I don't require any storage.

```
Configure.Features.Disable<TimeoutManager>();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use RavenDB, then you will have to specify another storage type.  If you do not want to use storage at all, turning off the features that use storage should work.  In 4.0 that can be done by using Feature class.  Example:

```
Configure.Features.Disable<Sagas>();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use sql server then you must use NserviceBus.Nhibernate If you need more information then let me know